# Running Web Audio API in the background on iOS with Ionic Capacitor React for seamless MP3 looping?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, cordova, ionic-framework

I am currently developing a mobile app using Ionic Capacitor React and I need to play an MP3 file in a seamless and gapless loop in the background even when the app is closed. I have tried using the Web Audio API to achieve this, but I have encountered some issues.

When the app is in the foreground, the Web Audio API works perfectly, and the MP3 file loops seamlessly without any gaps. However, when the app is closed, the audio stops playing after a few seconds, and I cannot get it to resume without reopening the app.

I have tried using the Background Moode plugin to keep the app running in the background, but this does not seem to work either.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution? Is it possible to run the Web Audio API in the background on iOS with Ionic Capacitor React, and if so, how can I achieve seamless and gapless looping of an MP3 file?

```
 const createTrack = async () => {
    BackgroundMode.enable();
    BackgroundMode.disableBatteryOptimizations();
    const audioCtx = new window.AudioContext();
    const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    const arrayBuffer = await fetch(
      '../assets/sounds/shortFan.mp3',
      ).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
      const audioBuffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
      
      source.buffer = audioBuffer;
      source.loop = true;
      source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
      source.start();
      audioCtx.resume();
}
```

here is some code ive been messing with the looop is perfect and gapless but once app is closed it stops playing. if i use an audio element it keeps playing in background but the loop has gaps in it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the iOS and Android device's operating system throttles background tasks and apps, in order to play a sequence of audio files while the app is in background mode or asleep you'll need to use a plugin that bridges your app to the device's native os api.  The native os does support playing a queue of background audio.

You could of course [write your own plugin to do this](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/creating-plugins), but I've been successfully using the [capacitor-plugin-playlist](https://github.com/phiamo/capacitor-plugin-playlist) plugin with Ionic Capacitor.

Comment: tyring to implement this method getting an error "unsupported URL" I also had to use --force on the instal since im using capacitor 4 that could be the issue

Comment: The specifics of the capacitor-plugin-playlist are beyond the scope of your question. The answer to your question is that you need to use a plugin that interfaces directly with the OS's audio player capabilities (eg AVQueuePlayer in iOS). You cannot rely on the web audio api when your app is in background mode.  The various plugins that try to keep your app awake while in background mode will not be accepted by Apple and Google: they restrict most background app functionality to preserve device battery. Take a look at or post a question on capacitor-plugin-playlist issues for troubleshooting.